# Best practice for working with less, or minified CSS

Tags: css, firebug, less

I'm considering using less in an upcoming project but have been trying to figure out the best way to work with it while in development.

Usually when developing a site I'll write my html and css then start testing it in the browser, see how it looks, refine, reload, and repeat the whole process until I'm happy with how everything looks.

A crucial part of the process is using the Inspect Element feature in the browser to identify the piece of CSS I need to change. Usually just by looking at the line number I know exactly where to go in my CSS file.

But if I use Less (or any other method of combining/compressing my CSS) it makes the line numbers useless. I know I could use Find to search for the section of code but line numbers are much faster.

This is especially true when working on a project that involves other developers or large CSS files.

I just wondered how others deal with this, or maybe there's a better process?

Comment: Why not just minify the CSS *after* everything looks the way you want?

Comment: @Colin: What happens when it looks the way OP wants it, and a series of users email in complaining "on my mac your site looks like junk because of xxxx and yyyy"?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: I assumed separate dev (un-minified) and production (minified) copies would be kept. I was not clear about that.

Comment: @Colin and to all people answered here: LESS is not about minification. It is a language to generate CSS files. The user works on a LESS file, and this generates *compiled* CSS. There is no process, such minification, that works on CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Minified CSS really should only be going out to the production version of your site. When you're performing tests/changes etc, this should all be done in some test or development version of your site in a secondary server area where you can have the line-numbers version of css available. The same would go for JavaScript. On the production viewable copy, you want it minified. In development, you don't.

In any event, you should always have 2 copies of your css. The first copy is the primary source copy that is your development copy. It has all of your properly formatted styles with line-breaks in it. The other is the very latest minified version of your css that went to production. This will allow you to switch between the 2 files rapidly in the event that you need to work something out, assuming your site uses some sort of templated delivery (layout pages, master pages, or whatever).

The minified version will only be useful in the final delivery. All other needs should use the master copy. It might not be a bad idea to put a configuration in server-side portion of your site that determines what style sheet to use. That way you can simply change a configuration setting and go into a "debug" mode.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel - that's how I handle it. A build script minifies the CSS (*and JS*) before each release is FTP'ed to production. I just have a switch in PHP like:

```
if ($config->prod()) {
    // incldue the minfied css
} else {
    // include all the original files
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I use an ant build script to make a production version:

1. it "condense" multiple css files in one
2. then it minify them with YUI compressor
3. same for scripts
4. (page recomposition to point to the newly generated files)

this way you divide your http request for those files, and gain some bandwith from 30% to 70% i'd say. depends on gzip also.

in my case, the dev version have:
18 css weighting 178ko
reduced down to 1 css at 96ko in the production version

Answer (score 0):

I personally use tools to minify and inject the CSS into the browser each time i save my Less file. So i see each change immediately. This way it's pretty clear what just happened. I don't need the referencing line numbers that much any more.

I recently started using [source maps](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors), to see the correct file and line numbers (of my less files) when inspecting CSS in the browser again. I think that is what you are looking for. I personally don't need this extra fanciness that much.